# Dynamic-Image-Resize Plugin does not output anything

Tags: images

I'm having trouble using the ["Dynamic-Image-Resize"](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Dynamic-Image-Resize) plugin by "Kaiser Franz Josef". 
In my template I'm adding following code:

```
$imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "Full");
$image_path = $imgsrc[0];

dynamic_image_resize( array(
    'src'     => $image_path    
    ,'width'   => 60
    ,'height'  => 100
    ,'classes' => 'thumb'
) );
```

It just outputs nothing, neither it give any error. I have made sure that the image path is correct.
How can I find out where is the problem?

If I var_dump the output of the above function, I get following:

```
object(oxoDynamicImageResize)#507 (1) { ["atts"]=> array(4) { ["src"]=> string(55) "http://localhost:81/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/1.jpg" ["width"]=> int(60) ["height"]=> int(100) ["classes"]=> string(5) "thumb" } }
```

I will highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ask the right guy

Which you just did, so... here's your answer from the developer. :)

### What does the right output tell us?

First of all, the public `dynamic_image_resize()` API function is just a wrapper for the singleton itself. When you take a closer look at the class, you'll notice a [`__toString()`](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Dynamic-Image-Resize/blob/master/dynamic_img_resize.php#L66)  method, which is the *magical* method that returns the output.

As you've seen from your `var_dump()`, you get back the exact object (the class name indicates that), but not the string. So the `__toString()` method didn't trigger and therefore doesn't call the output. It just called the `__construct()` method with your attributes, so you see the exact same thing set as the class properties, that you defined when calling the class.

### How to "fix" something that isn't broken?

The class, as stated previously, uses the `__toString()` method. This method - as most *magical* PHP methods - only trigger under a certain condition. In this case, when you `echo` the output.

So your solution would simply be to `echo dynamic_image_resize()`. Here's it written quickly (not tested).

```
echo dynamic_image_resize( array(
     'src'     => array_shift( wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
         get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() )
        ,"Full"
     ) )
    ,'width'   => 60
    ,'height'  => 100
    ,'classes' => 'thumb'
) );
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the great work and the detailed answer.